# Password must contain any one of the following criteria

Tags: javascript, regex

Password must contain any one of the following criteria

1)One Uppercase 
2)one lower case 
3)one Number 
4)one special character.

in the above criteria if any three-match then it's allowed to a valid password.

like below format.

1) One number, one lower case alphabet, one uppercase alphabet ---> valid password

or

2)one number, one lower case alphabet, and one special character ---> valid password

or

3)one number, one uppercase alphabet, and one special character ---> valid password.

Please help me how to write the regular expression for the above criteria.

my requirement is any three combinations one number, one alphabet, one special character. it's like permutation combination format.
if I write /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-._@^]).{8,16}/ format I need to verify so many conditions .so any another way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess that the reason your question is getting downvoted is because you haven't tried doing this yourself yet; have a go at it - read some regex - there are online tools to test your regex live and fix it. Try your best to get there and then ask for specific help if you run into issues.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  I  tried to like this (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-._@^]).{8,12}. but its's a reputation process.  in thsi case i need to verify so many condtions.

Comment: Post your code, and describe the problem in it.

Comment: Is the order of pswd chars is important for you?

Comment: the order is not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your special characters are [\^$.|?*+()

1) One number, one lower case alphabet, one uppercase alphabet ---> valid password

```
[0-9][a-z][A-Z]
```

or

2) one number, one lower case alphabet, and one special character ---> valid password

```
[0-9][a-z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)]
```

or

3) one number, one uppercase alphabet, and one special character ---> valid password.

```
[0-9][A-Z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)]
```

Combine them with OR (|)

```
[0-9][a-z][A-Z]|[0-9][a-z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)]|[0-9][A-Z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)]
```

Comment: I try with the above format but still issue. my requirement is any three combinations one number, one alphabet, one special character. it's like permutation combination format.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the pswd chars is not important so:

1. One number, one lower case alphabet, one uppercase alphabet ---> valid password:
   `\d[a-z][A-Z]`
2. One number, one lower case alphabet, and one special character ---> valid password:
   `\d[a-z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)]`
3. One number, one uppercase alphabet, and one special character ---> valid password:
   `\d[A-Z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)]`

So if it's combined in one regex:
`(\d[a-z][A-Z])|(\d[a-z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)])|(\d[A-Z][\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)])`

Check it up [here](https://regex101.com/r/iSTZdh/1)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I need any three combinations. then I consider that a password is a valid password. If my Password raj then it's not a valid password. if my password Ra1 then it's not a valid password like etc...